# How command Windows to give scroll bars for programs Adobe Acrobat and IrfanView?

Tags: scrollbar

Why programs on Windows 10 don't give me scroll bars? In Adobe Acrobat, I can't scroll down to see whole window. In IrfanView, I can't scroll right to see whole file name. See below.
[image]

Images below hail from [Freemake.com](https://www.freemake.com/blog/irfanview-image-editor-and-viewer-for-windows/) and [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Panorama-Image-Using-IrfanView).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the first image you have a modal sheet which is not designed to scroll. Your viewport is too small for it. You need the change either your screen resolution or the display scale. Right click your desktop > Display Settings

[image]

For the second, I've no idea. Check if there's an app update, or contact the makers.